# if element class = element class or data-attr do something

Tags: javascript, jquery, menu, custom-data-attribute, megamenu

Hi have two different megamenus, which cannot be displayed by css based on the html markup. Therefore I want to use Javascript/jQuery.

```
HTML of links:
<li id="menu-item-154" class="tg-submenu__link .tg-submenu__tg menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-154">
<a href="#">MEGAMENU-LINK1</a></li>

<li id="menu-item-155" class="tg-submenu__link .tg-submenu__abteilungen menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-155">
<a href="#">MEGA MENU LINK2</a></li>

HTML of the mega menu containers
<div class="tg-submenu tg-submenu__tg" data-trigger="tg-submenu__tg">
</div>

<div class="tg-submenu tg-submenu__abteilungen" data-trigger="tg-submenu__abteilungen">
</div>
```

So I'd like to run a function, which checks if the links has the same classes (.tg-submenu__tg and .tg-submenu__abteilungen) or the same data-trigger attribute and if so add a class to the particular mega menu container by hovering the corresponding link. I could easily write two separate functions which test this isolated but I need an universal function, cause the links may change or more links may be added in the future.

Comment: you have a `.` in your class `.tg-submenu__tg`

Comment: this is intended, since I saw such an example on a site. It seems to simplify the checking process (with the data attribute in that particular case), but I was not able or good enough to figure out the javascript of the site, cause it was obfuscated. Of course I change this, if someone has a solution by checking the classes rather than a class and a data-attribute

Comment: Threre should not be a . inside the class attribute

Comment: So bind a click event and read the data attribute. What is the issue?... oh wait... to me it seems like you have it backwards. Why is the data attribute on what is being opened and not on what is being clicked?

Comment: Problem is that I don't know how to make it universal to use. My knowledge ends where I check if two particular classes matches (with .hasClass), which I already know. I'd like to have a function, which compares this and do sth. After that I would like to call this function multiple times and within this new call functions I would like to define the classnames which should be equal to the mega menu container classes or data-attribute. So I could add new call functions when links are added. Plus in my scenario I'd need two separate functions to check if both classes matches up to now

Comment: The `data-trigger="tg-submenu__abteilungen"` should be on the LI, not the div. Than it is simple as `$("li.tg-submenu__link").on("click", function () { console.log($(this).data("trigger")) })`

Comment: May you have a look at transactpro.lv – thats the way I'd like to go. I am using a Wordpress theme. Adding data-attribute to links, would need at least jQuery aswell (or extending the menu walker), whereas adding data-attribute to the mega menu containers can be done via html, since it is custom coded

Answer (score 1):

- problem is in your class ".tg-submenu__abteilungen" here "." not
  acceptable
- You can use .hasClass('classname')

> Code

```
$(document).on('li','click',function(){
    if($(this).hasClass('tg-submenu__abteilungen')){
    // console.log('Link has tg-submenu__abteilungen CLASS');
    } else {
    //console.log('Link hasn't tg-submenu__abteilungen CLASS');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is what I came up by using .hasClass, which was adviced by @Darshit Hedpara:

```
jQuery(document).ready (function ($) {
var $tg_body = $('body'),
    $tg_top_menu = $('ul.nav'),
    $tg_submenu_link = $('.tg-submenu__link');

    $tg_submenu_link.hover(function() { 
    if (! $(this).closest('li.tg-submenu__link').length || $(this).hasClass('tg-submenu__link') && $(this).hasClass('tg-submenu__link--tgkonz')) {
        $tg_body.addClass('tg-submenu__tg--active tg-showDropdown');
        $tg_body.removeClass('tg-hover').addClass('tg-hover');
        tg_menu_hover_triggered = true;
    }
    else {
        $tg_body.addClass('tg-submenu__abteilungen--active tg-showDropdown');
        $tg_body.removeClass('tg-hover').addClass('tg-hover');
    }
}, function () {
    $tg_body.removeClass('tg-submenu__tg--active tg-submenu__abteilungen--active tg-showDropdown');
    $tg_body.addClass('tg-submenu__removing');

    tg_menu_hover_triggered = false;

    setTimeout(function () {
        if (! $tg_body.hasClass('tg-showDropdown')) {
            $tg_body.removeClass('tg-hover').removeClass('tg-submenu__removing');
        }
    }, 200);
});
});
```

This is not for universal purpose. For example, if I decide to include a third megamenu, I would to rewrite the code. If someone has an idea to make this universal with a callback function or has some ideas to make this a way more performant/best practice, feel free to repost. I'll keep an eye on this topic!